# HTML/CSS code for creating a Table

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on this assignment for school. I have two issues I can't find the solution for.

HTML Validation gives me this error - A table row was 5 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (4).
From line 72, column 5; to line 72, column 9

As you can see on the table there is an extra column at the end that is very small. I am not sure how to eliminate that.

```css
table {
 margin: auto;
 border: 1px solid #3399cc;
 width: 90%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td, th {
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #3399cc;
    }

    td {
 text-align: center;
    }

    .text {
 text-align: left;
    }

    tr:nth-of-type(even) {
 background-color: #f5fafc
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="package-names">Package Name</th>
    <th id="description">Description</th>
    <th id="nights">Nights</th>
    <th id="cost-per-person">Cost per Person</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="package-names">Weekend Escape</td>
    <td headers="description" class="text">Two breakfasts, a     trail map, a picnic snack</td>
    <td headers="nights">2</td>
    <td headers="cost-per-person">$450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="package-names">Zen Retreat</td>
    <td headers="description" class="text">Four breakfasts, a trail map, a pass for daily yoga</td>
    <td headers="nights">4</td>
    <td headers="cost-per-person">$600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="package-names">Kayak Away</td>
    <td headers="description" class="text">Two breakfasts, two hours of kayak rental daily, a trail map</td>
    <td headers="nights">2</td>
    <td headers="cost-per-person">$500<td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Here you forgot to close your `td` and instead made a new one `<td headers="cost-per-person">$500<td>`. The ending `<td>` should be `</td>`, which is probably just a typo on your end.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the very last `td` line:

```
<td headers="cost-per-person">$500<td>
```

The last tag has to be  a *closing* tag: `</td>`instead of `<td>`

```css
table {
 margin: auto;
 border: 1px solid #3399cc;
 width: 90%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    td, th {
 padding: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #3399cc;
    }

    td {
 text-align: center;
    }

    .text {
 text-align: left;
    }

    tr:nth-of-type(even) {
 background-color: #f5fafc
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="package-names">Package Name</th>
    <th id="description">Description</th>
    <th id="nights">Nights</th>
    <th id="cost-per-person">Cost per Person</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="package-names">Weekend Escape</td>
    <td headers="description" class="text">Two breakfasts, a     trail map, a picnic snack</td>
    <td headers="nights">2</td>
    <td headers="cost-per-person">$450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="package-names">Zen Retreat</td>
    <td headers="description" class="text">Four breakfasts, a trail map, a pass for daily yoga</td>
    <td headers="nights">4</td>
    <td headers="cost-per-person">$600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="package-names">Kayak Away</td>
    <td headers="description" class="text">Two breakfasts, two hours of kayak rental daily, a trail map</td>
    <td headers="nights">2</td>
    <td headers="cost-per-person">$500</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Weel that's pretty embarassing! Thank you for the help fellas! I scratched my head for an hour over this haha.

Answer (score 0):

You're simply missing a slash in your closing `<td>` on the last row, which should look like so:

```
<td headers="cost-per-person">$500</td>
```

Fixed Version: http://codepen.io/alexgurrola/pen/EWrNEv?editors=1000